# how to find out which option is selected in a <select> and how to escape the name?

Tags: jquery, html

i have got this HTML code:

```
<select name="audience[8787330733][value]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="80">Everyone</option>
  <option selected="1" value="50">Friends of Friends</option>
  <option value="40">Friends</option>
</select>
```

now i want to find out which of these options are selected.

i tried

```
$('select[name="audience[8787330733][value]"] option:selected').text();
```

but this does not work :(
I think I didn't escaped the name in the right way...

Thank you for your answers!!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You should reference elements by id as it's the fastest selector as in @Arif's answer.
2. If it is not possible for you to change the html you can try:

(escaping special symbols in jQuery selectors can be achieved by using double backslashes)

```
$('select[name=audience\\[8787330733\\]\\[value\\]] option:selected').text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TfThK/ - tested on your example.

Comment: Good answer that actually works with what's given without needing changes to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   <select name="audience[8787330733][value]" class="className">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="80">Everyone</option>
  <option selected="1" value="50">Friends of Friends</option>
  <option value="40">Friends</option>
    </select>
```

Jquery 
If you want to get selected text

```
$('.className option:selected').text();
```

If you want to get selected value

```
$('.className option:selected').val();
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4tySt/) DEMO

Comment: I don't recommend this answer, as class selector is the slowest selector in jQuery. Reference - http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Comment: I'm voting 1 on this because it took me an hour to find the syntax to get a value by class name.  Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Use id in select:

```
<select id="audience" name="audience[8787330733][value]">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="80">Everyone</option>
  <option selected="1" value="50">Friends of Friends</option>
  <option value="40">Friends</option>
</select>
```

Then try with the following code:

```
$('#audience').val();
```

or

```
$('#audience selected:option').val();
```

And if you want to get selected text then just replace

```
val()
```

with

```
text()
```